# Ist "Sinn machen" im Österreichischen Deutsch zulässig?

Tags: phrase, austrian

Im [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sinn#Bedeutung4) wird "etwas macht einen Sinn" als umgangssprachlich eingestuft und es ist demnach in der Schrift ja nicht zulässig.

Doch wie sieht es im Österreichischen Deutsch aus, für welches ja das [Österreichische Wörterbuch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichisches_W%C3%B6rterbuch) gilt?

Comment: *Zulässigkeit* ist eine normative Frage und bestimmt sich als solche nach den (oft impliziten) sozialen Normen, in der die Sprache gesprochen wird. Diese sozialen Normen werden in Gruppen ausgehandelt. Die Antwort, ob eine bestimmte Sprechweise *zulässig* ist, hängt also von der Gruppe ab, und kann in dieser Allgemeinheit nicht beantwortet werden. Es gibt keine autoritative Instanz, die in dieser Allgemeinheit darüber entscheidet, selbst der Duden kann das nicht.

Comment: Auch umgangssprachlich sagt man allenfalls "etwas macht keinen Sinn" oder "etwas macht Sinn", wie man ja auch sagt "etwas macht Spaß/Laune", nicht jedoch "etwas macht einen Sinn" oder "etwas macht zwei bis drei Sinn". Verboten ist es natürlich nicht und ob geschrieben oder gesprochen, das dürfte für die Häufigkeit bedeutend sein, nicht jedoch für die Zulässigkeit. Bücher können versuchen die Sprache präzise so zu nutzen, wie das Milieu, das durch sie dargestellt wird.

Comment: Hier ein 50minütiges Video zur Frage, ob es guter Stil ist, allerdings ohne Betrachtung spezifisch der österreicherischen Verwendung: http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/sprache/sinn-machen.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auch wenn das ÖWB (Österreichische Wörterbuch) im Gegensatz zum Duden ein amtliches (von der Bundesregierung herausgegebenes) Dokument ist, ist es trotzdem nicht so, dass es vorgibt, welche Begriffe wir in Österreich verwenden dürfen. Es regelt nur, wie welche Wörter von österreichischen Beamten und Schülern zu schreiben sind (bis auf »Geschoß« ohnehin immer gleich wie in Deutschland).

Die Floskel *»etwas macht Sinn«* war, als ich (geb. 1965) noch in die Schule ging, in Österreich ebenso falsch wie im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum. Richtig war nur *»etwas ist sinnvoll«* oder *»etwas ergibt Sinn«*. Die Phrase *»etwas macht Sinn«* entstand durch schlampige Übersetzungen aus dem Englischen (*to make sense*) und unterliegt in ihrer Häufigkeitsverteilung keinen regionalen Schwankungen, weil die Phrase eben nicht in einer bestimmten Region entstanden ist.

Die Phrase ist durchaus »zulässig«. Es gibt keine Regel, die sie verbietet. Ältere Menschen, die sie nicht von ihrer Jugend an kennen, halten sie für falsch oder zumindest für stilistisch bedenklich. Jüngere, die mit dieser Phrase aufgewachsen sind, verwenden sie auch bedenkenlos in geschriebenen Texten, und halten sie auch für richtig.

Comment: In einem Deutschaufsatz in der Schule würde man wahrscheinlich aber Abzug für Stil bekommen.

Comment: Wie würde das denn wirklich in einem Deutschaufsatz beurteilt werden, oder würde das ein Lektor ändern?

Comment: Wirklich "Geschoß" oder nicht doch "Geschoss" (Etage, Projektil)? Im Deutschen Geschoss.

Comment: @userunknown: Ob am Ende einer Silbe *ß* oder *ss* kommt, hängt davon ab, ob der Vokal davor lang oder kurz ausgesprochen wird. Lang = *ß*, kurz = *ss*  (Der Schneider kennt meine Ma*ß*e, im Tigel schmilzt eine Ma*ss*e). Nachdem das Geschoß (sowohl Projektil als auch Stockwerk) in Österreich mit einem langen O ausgesprochen wird, kann man es hier auch mit *ß* schreiben. Die Schreibweise mit *ss* ist aber auch zulässig.

Comment: Siehe auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Österreichisches_Deutsch#Schreibweise Dort sogar noch ein zweites Wort das in Ö anders geschrieben wird: *»das Kücken«*. Mir war bis jetzt gar nicht bekannt, dass man das in Deutschland ohne c (also *»das Küken«*) schreibt und offenbar mit langem Ü ausspricht. (In Österreich mit kurzem Ü).

Comment: @tofro: Ich glaube, das hängt vom Alter des Lehrers ab. Lehrer, die kurz vor der Pension stehen, werden in diesem Fall eher schlechten Stil attestieren als junge, die frisch von der Uni kommen.

Comment: Meine Kinder bekommen das von Lehrern fast jeden Alters angestrichen. (Was sie nicht daran hindert, es trotzdem zu schreiben...)

Comment: @tofro: dann rede mal mit den Lehrern über den stetigen Wandel lebender Sprachen. Die Lehrer werden deine Kinder nicht daran hindern, im Alltag »Sinn machen« zu verwenden. Sie bewirken nur, dass die Kinder weniger Freude an der Schule haben.

Comment: Dann bin ich ja froh, da den richtigen Riecher gehabt zu haben. Traffik, Kasten, Paradeiser und Sessel sind mir zwar bekannt, aber Geschoß habe ich noch nie gehört. Man lernt doch nie aus.

Comment: @userunknown: Das Wort *»Traffik«* gibt es nicht. Du meinst wohl *»die Trafik«* (ein F, ein K, kein C, Aussprache [tʁaˈfɪk]). Das ist Geschäft in Österreich mit weniger als ca. 10 m² Verkaufsfläche, in dem Zigaretten und Zeitungen verkauft werden. Dann gibt es noch *»der Traffic«* (zwei F, kein K, dafür ein C, Aussprache [tɹæfɪk]). Das ist ein Fachbegriff aus der IT-Branche, mit dem die Menge der übertragenen Daten bezeichnet wird.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Danke für die Trafik. Traffic ist aber wohl einfach das englische Wort "Verkehr", welches eben auch für Datenverkehr benutzt wird, allerdings nicht für die Menge.